# C++ on vscode: Debug get error but run code without debug is still run

Tags: c++, debugging

This is my code to sorting array 2D use extra array or don't. I use funtion pointer like this

```
int main() {

input();
printf("Array 2D: \n");
output();
printf("After sorting: \n");
solve(sortWithoutUseExtraArr);
output();
}
```

and my funtion:

```
void sortWithoutUseExtraArr { ..... }
void solve(void (*sort)()) {
    (*sort)();
}
```

When i run without debug. It run perfectlly. But when i start debug. It get error:`too many arguments to function 'void solve()'`

Can everyone explain this for me. Thank you so much.
And sorry because my english is too bad!

EDIT: the entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int a[MAX][MAX];
int row, column;

void input();
void output();
void sortArray1D();
void sortUseExtraArr();
void sortWithoutUseExtraArr();
void solve();

int main() {
    
    input();
    printf("Array 2D: \n");
    output();
    printf("After sorting: \n");
    solve(sortWithoutUseExtraArr);
    output();
    
}

void input() {

    printf("Nhap so hang: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Nhap so cot: ");
    scanf("%d", &column);
    for (int i = 0; i < row;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column;++j)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
}

void output() {
    for (int i = 0; i < row;++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column;++j) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void sortArray1D(int arr[],int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {     
           if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {    
               int temp = arr[i];    
               arr[i] = arr[j];    
               arr[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    }    
}

void sortUseExtraArr() {
    int b[MAX * MAX];
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column;++j)
        {
            b[n] = a[i][j];
            ++n;
        }
    }
    
    sortArray1D(b, n);
    
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column;++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = b[d];
            ++d;
        }
    }
}

void sortWithoutUseExtraArr() {

    int n = row * column;

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i / column][i % column] > a[j / column][j % column])
            {
                int temp = a[i / column][i % column];
                a[i / column][i % column] = a[j / column][j % column];
                a[j / column][j % column] = temp;
            }
        

}
    }
    
}

void solve(void (*sort)()) {
    (*sort)();
}
```

Comment: Could you post more context from the error message?

Comment: ***Can everyone explain this for me*** I think you need to show more code for any hope of someone explaining this.

Comment: you write illegal C++, at least what you post, show a minimal complete C++ file with the problem

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mnXyM6A.png
Here is error i get, and my source code is: https://github.com/betty2310/SorttingArray2D/blob/master/main.c